# How to understand `MonadUnliftIO`'s requirement of "no stateful monads"?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, classy-prelude

I've looked over https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/tale-of-two-brackets, though skimming some parts, and I still don't quite understand the core issue "`StateT` is bad, `IO` is OK", other than vaguely getting the sense that Haskell allows one to write bad `StateT` monads (or in the ultimate example in the article, `MonadBaseControl` instead of `StateT`, I think).

In the haddocks, the following law must be satisfied:

```
askUnliftIO >>= (\u -> liftIO (unliftIO u m)) = m
```

So this appears to be saying that state is not mutated in the monad `m` when using `askUnliftIO`. But to my mind, in `IO`, the entire world can be the state. I could be reading and writing to a text file on disk, for instance.

To quote [another article by Michael](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern),

> False purity We say WriterT and StateT are pure, and technically they
>   are. But let's be honest: if you have an application which is entirely
>   living within a StateT, you're not getting the benefits of restrained
>   mutation that you want from pure code. May as well call a spade a
>   spade, and accept that you have a mutable variable.

This makes me think this is indeed the case: with IO we are being honest, with `StateT`, we are not being honest about mutability ... but that seems another issue than what the law above is trying to show; after all, `MonadUnliftIO` is assuming `IO`. I'm having trouble understanding conceptually how `IO` is more restrictive than something else.

**Update 1**

After sleeping (some), I am still confused but am gradually getting less so as the day wears on. I worked out the law proof for `IO`. I realized the presence of `id` in the README. In particular,

```
instance MonadUnliftIO IO where
  askUnliftIO = return (UnliftIO id)
```

So `askUnliftIO` would appear to return an `IO (IO a)` on an `UnliftIO m`.

```
Prelude> fooIO = print 5
Prelude> :t fooIO
fooIO :: IO ()
Prelude> let barIO :: IO(IO ()); barIO = return fooIO
Prelude> :t barIO
barIO :: IO (IO ())
```

Back to the law, it really appears to be saying that state is not mutated in the monad `m` when doing a round trip on the transformed monad (`askUnliftIO`), where the round trip is `unLiftIO` -> `liftIO`.

Resuming the example above, `barIO :: IO ()`, so if we do `barIO >>= (u -> liftIO (unliftIO u m))`, then `u :: IO ()` and `unliftIO u == IO ()`, then `liftIO (IO ()) == IO ()`. **So since everything has basically been applications of `id` under the hood, we can see that no state was changed, even though we are using `IO`. Crucially, I think, what is important is that the value in `a` is never run, nor is any other state modified, as a result of using `askUnliftIO`. If it did, then like in the case of `randomIO :: IO a`, we would not be able to get the same value had we not run `askUnliftIO` on it. (Verification attempt 1 below)

*But*, it still seems like we *could* do the same for other Monads, even if they do maintain state. But I also see how, for some monads, we may not be able to do so. Thinking of a contrived example: each time we access the value of type `a` contained in the stateful  monad, some internal state is changed.

**Verification attempt 1**

```
> fooIO >> askUnliftIO
5
> fooIOunlift = fooIO >> askUnliftIO
> :t fooIOunlift
fooIOunlift :: IO (UnliftIO IO)
> fooIOunlift
5
```

Good so far, but confused about why the following occurs:

```
 > fooIOunlift >>= (\u -> unliftIO u)

<interactive>:50:24: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `IO b'
                  with actual type `IO a0 -> IO a0'
    * Probable cause: `unliftIO' is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: unliftIO u
      In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `(\ u -> unliftIO u)'
      In the expression: fooIOunlift >>= (\ u -> unliftIO u)
    * Relevant bindings include
        it :: IO b (bound at <interactive>:50:1)
```

Comment: The advantages of `StateT s IO` over `IORef`s are real, and they have nothing to do with purity. A `StateT` "variable" can't escape its enclosing `runStateT`. That makes it clear to both humans and the compiler just when it exists. It can be allocated on the stack or in a register, and even unboxed automatically. An `IORef` can be passed to a function, stored in a data structure, etc. It is always allocated on the heap and its contents must be boxed. If you need an accumulator for a tight loop, an `IORef` is typically a lousy choice. I know that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @dfeuer does GHC actually use that knowledge to do optimizations like that on the `s` in a `StateT s m a`?

Comment: @ephrion Oh yes, most definitely. GHC's representation of `IO` is bogus, but it makes it very convenient to apply optimizations designed for pure code to code involving `IO`. Once the newtypes are unwrapped, `StateT s IO a` is just `s -> State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, (a, s) #)`. Despite the difficulty of nested constructed product result analysis, this tends to unbox pretty well in my experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "StateT is bad, IO is OK"

That's not really the point of the article. The idea is that `MonadBaseControl` permits some confusing (and often undesirable) behaviors with stateful monad transformers in the presence of concurrency and exceptions.

`finally :: StateT s IO a -> StateT s IO a -> StateT s IO a` is a great example. If you use the "`StateT` is attaching a mutable variable of type `s` onto a monad `m`" metaphor, then you might expect that the finalizer action gets access to the most recent `s` value when an exception was thrown.

`forkState :: StateT s IO a -> StateT s IO ThreadId` is another one. You might expect that the state modifications from the input would be reflected in the original thread.

```hs
lol :: StateT Int IO [ThreadId]
lol = do
  for [1..10] $ \i -> do
    forkState $ modify (+i)
```

You might expect that `lol` could be rewritten (modulo performance) as `modify (+ sum [1..10])`. But that's not right. The implementation of `forkState` just passes the initial state to the forked thread, and then *can never retrieve any state modifications*. The easy/common understanding of `StateT` fails you here.

Instead, you have to adopt a more nuanced view of `StateT s m a` as "a transformer that provides a thread-local immutable variable of type `s` which is implicitly threaded through a computation, and it is possible to replace that local variable with a new value of the same type for future steps of the computation." (more or less a verbose english retelling of the `s -> m (a, s)`) With this understanding, the behavior of `finally` becomes a bit more clear: it's a local variable, so it does not survive exceptions. Likewise, `forkState` becomes more clear: it's a thread-local variable, so obviously a change to a different thread won't affect any others.

This is *sometimes* what you want. But it's usually not how people write code IRL and it often confuses people.

For a long time, the default choice in the ecosystem to do this "lowering" operation was `MonadBaseControl`, and this had a bunch of downsides: hella confusing types, difficult to implement instances, impossible to derive instances, sometimes confusing behavior. Not a great situation.

`MonadUnliftIO` restricts things to a simpler set of monad transformers, and is able to provide relatively simple types, derivable instances, and always predictable behavior. The cost is that `ExceptT`, `StateT`, etc transformers can't use it.

The underlying principle is: by restricting what is possible, we make it easier to understand what might happen. `MonadBaseControl` is extremely powerful and general, and quite difficult to use and confusing as a result. `MonadUnliftIO` is less powerful and general, but it's much easier to use.

> So this appears to be saying that state is not mutated in the monad m when using askUnliftIO.

This isn't true - the law is stating that `unliftIO` shouldn't do anything with the monad transformer aside from lowering it into `IO`. Here's something that breaks that law:

```hs
newtype WithInt a = WithInt (ReaderT Int IO a)
  deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader Int)

instance MonadUnliftIO WithInt where
  askUnliftIO = pure (UnliftIO (\(WithInt readerAction) -> runReaderT 0 readerAction))
```

Let's verify that this breaks the law given: `askUnliftIO >>= (\u -> liftIO (unliftIO u m)) = m`.

```hs
test :: WithInt Int
test = do
  int <- ask
  print int
  pure int

checkLaw :: WithInt ()
checkLaw = do
  first <- test
  second <- askUnliftIO >>= (\u -> liftIO (unliftIO u test))
  when (first /= second) $
    putStrLn "Law violation!!!"
```

The value returned by `test` and the `askUnliftIO ...` lowering/lifting are different, so the law is broken. Furthermore, the observed effects are different, which isn't great either.